# Firestore rule to only allow update on value change

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a function that is evaluating if an update is allowed for a user's profile. As you can see, the `validProfileUpdate` function calls the `validFieldUpdate` function for each field I have listed (in this case `name` and `age`). When I execute an update command for just one of the fields it will work, but when I uncomment the second one (in this case, for `age`) it will always fail. I only want these fields to be allowed to update based on if there's a change in data between what's being sent in and what already exists.

```
function validProfileUpdate() {
  let validKeys = ['name', 'age'];

  return request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).changedKeys().hasOnly(validKeys) &&
    validFieldUpdate('name', validName()) &&
    validFieldUpdate('age', validAge());
}
```

```
function validFieldUpdate(field, condition) {
  return !(field in request.resource.data.keys()) ||
  (request.resource.data[field] != resource.data[field] && condition);
}
```

What I'm having difficulty with is that I figured the line `!(field in request.resource.data.keys())` in `validFieldUpdate` would catch any fields not included in the update that's sent and it would return `true` but for some reason that's not happening when I add the second field `age`.

So in summary, this works and only allows updates after it's sent for names that aren't Joe:

```
const profilePayload = {
  name: 'Joe'
}

await userProfileRef.update({ ...profilePayload })
```

But this is blocked by the rules 100% of the time:

```
const profilePayload = {
  name: 'Joe'
  age: 25

}

await userProfileRef.update({ ...profilePayload })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `affectedKeys` to compare the items rather than `changedKeys` as changedKeys only accounts for key values that are different from the original, a problem if the value stays the same.

```js
  let validKeys = ['name', 'age'];
if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(validKeys);
```

Affected:

> which lists any keys that have been added to, removed from or modified from the Map calling diff() compared to the Map passed to diff()

Changed:

> which lists any keys that appear in both the Map calling diff() and the Map passed to diff(), but whose values are not equal.

Comment: I actually completely removed that line and it still wouldn't work with both `name` and `age`. I even replaced the conditions I check the fields against and just made it `true` to be as simple as possible and it's still failing.

Comment: Then the issue is that your  field in keys doesn't resolve correctly, the `in` is normally used for unordered list from the document resource. I have never seen it used the way you have but at first glance it appears ok. but effectively, you are doing the same as `keys().hasAll([field])` - I would swap that out and see how it goes - 
`if (!request.resource.data.keys().hasAll([field]))`